# How to use InetOrgPersonContextMapper class

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm authenticated and authorise to Active Directory by Spring Security.
But can not retrive LDAP attributes, for example MAIL.
I trying use InetOrgPersonContextMapper for it...

```
@Bean
public InetOrgPersonContextMapper inetOrgPersonContextMapper(){
    InetOrgPersonContextMapper contextMapper = new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();
    return contextMapper;
}
 @Bean
public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider(){
    LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator(),ldapAuthoritiesPopulator());
    ldapAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(inetOrgPersonContextMapper());
    return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

but when i trying retrive attributes in controller to i get ClassCastExeption

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    InetOrgPerson person = (InetOrgPerson)auth.getPrincipal();
```

Please tell me correct way for reitrive attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's no better way, but it's working.
If anybody know how can do it better, please tell me.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper(){
    return new LdapUserDetailsMapper(){
        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            InetOrgPersonContextMapper personContextMapper = new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();
            UserDetails cm = personContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities);
            String MAIL = ((InetOrgPerson)(personContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities))).getMail();
            String FullName = ((InetOrgPerson)(personContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities))).getDisplayName();
            System.out.println("MAIL: " + MAIL + " Full Name: " + FullName);
            return cm;
        }
    };
}
```